# updating/refreshing List with custom ListAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I am aware that there are plenty of similar questions, but they all have in common, that their solutions dont work with my list :(

I am trying to get my userList refreshing itself via the custom ArrayAdapter, when the database-contents are changed. In my case when i reset();

here my snippets (partial code):
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private MyUserListAdapter myUserlistAdapter; 
    public ArrayList<User> myUserList = new ArrayList<User>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //shortened the list-filling. but it works properly!
        User user = db.readUser(int);
        myUserList.add(user);
        myUserlistAdapter = new MyUserListAdapter(this, R.layout.row_main, myUserList);
        setListAdapter(myUserlistAdapter);

        //now when reset-button is hit, the listview should refresh itself
         bReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //this is what is posted in most questions, but it does nothing for me
                 //myUserlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 //getListView().invalidateViews();
            } });
```

and here myUserListAdapter.java:

```
public class MyUserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<User> userList;

public MyUserListAdapter(Context context,
        int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<User> userList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, userList);

    this.context = context;
    this.userList = userList;
}

public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.row_main, null);
    }

    User user = getItem(position);

    TextView tvUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
    ImageView ivVoted = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivVoted);

    tvUser.setText(user.getName());

    //abfrage ob hasVoted() = true muss noch eingebaut werden.
    if (user.getVoted().equals("1"))
        ivVoted.setImageResource(R.drawable.redcheck);
    else
        ivVoted.setImageResource(R.drawable.greencheck);
    return v;
}   
}
```

User.java is just a simple object-class. think its not the troublemaker here!

any help is appreciated!!! thx :-)

Comment: now what is happening is the application crashing ?

Comment: it is simply just not refreshing the listview --> updating the drawables showing my check-status

Comment: you already commented out that particular part of code and also if the data for the adapter is not changed how come the view will get changed ?

Comment: It doesn't show any change because you never change the data in the list view. All you do when you handle the onClick event is to refresh the views. But since they contain the same data as before, it will of course show the same.

Comment: keeping a reference to userList in your adapter is useless. just call getItem(position) when you need an item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to get my userList refreshing itself via the custom
>   ArrayAdapter, when the database-contents are changed.

Since you are using ArrayAdapter and not CursorAdapter when you update data in database your adapter won't refresh itself. Whenever you want to update ListView you need to provide new datasource for Adapter.

One possible solution is to create setter in adapter subclass that will change datasource of adapter.

**Pseudo code:**

```
/* setter in adapter subclass */
public void changeDataSource(ArrayList<User> newUserList) {
   this.userList = newUserList;
}
```

Then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` for `ListView` update.

Comment: this is an interesting idea. i will try it and give feedback lateron :)

Comment: i figured it now. used clear() on the userList and refilled it again from the database. this way the notify reaches the adapter and rebuilds it. though, i will continue thinking on a smarter solution :-)

Comment: why clear? just call setter that change datasource and immediately after call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: im trying the setter too. rookies don't develop so fast

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arrayAdapter.clear()
for(Object o : objects)
  arrayAdapter.add(o)
```

`clear()` and `add()` call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` itself.